# wpf richtextbox logic for dynamic text options

Tags: c#, wpf, logic, controls, richtextbox

I am trying to create a custom WPF RichTextBox control that does the following:

User can type any plain, un-formatted text.
As user edits text, control automatically sets items encapsulated in brackets as selectable options and unsets items that were originally encapsulated. For example:

Hello **[Bob, Rp]**, my name is **[Ro, Ho]**. --- the unselected items are Bob, Rp, Ro, and Ho

Hello **[** Bob **, Rp ]**, my name is **[Ro, Ho]**. --- the user left mouse clicks Bob (thus selecting Bob) and Rp, Ro, and Ho remain unselected

Hello **[** Bob **, Rp ]**, my name is [Ro, Ho. --- the user deleted the last ] but Bob remains selected, Rp remains unselected, and Ro and Ho is now considered regular text.

Finally, each sentence in the richtextbox can become unselected or selected. The sentence's background changes to a different color if unselected.

I'm not asking for a working solution but an idea on how to implement this control. I already made a working solution that does almost everything except anytime the user adds or deletes a bracket, all options reset to unselected. TextPointers and TextChangedEventArgs are really difficult to work with...

---

Comment: As for me, i have tried to separate text typing and such magic with brackets and selecting/unselecting.

Comment: @Spawn Do you mean the user would type in the text and then, in a different view, select/unselect options? If the user made a mistake when typing text and realizes it at the select/unselect view, then the select/unselect view will reset if the user goes back to change the text, right? I would still face the same problem either way :(

Comment: Anyone with any brilliant ideas on how I can implement this?